# Failed to start with loading Logstash config file

Tags: java, mysql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

I have a problem with connection JDBC MySQL connector:

> The signal HUP is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on
> this platform.

[image]

**item-index.conf**

[image]

The table 'Item' exists in the database. There have a data.

The connector version is the same as the mysql version - 8.0.25

Help me solve this problem.

Comment: That 'signal HUP is in use by the JVM' message comes from JRuby. See [this](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/523) logstash issue on github for more discussion. It does not prevent logstash from starting or working. It just prevents you asking logstash to reload pipelines using SIGHUP. So what is your actual issue?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought it was an error, since this message was shown. I tried run with '/logstash -f item-index.conf'. Everythings works - records are transferred from mysql to ES. Thanks